# How do I make Playwright in Python use a proxy?

Tags: python, playwright, browserstack, playwright-python

I am currently trying to get a cross browser testing solution from BrowserStack to work with all our company frameworks.

For Selenium this works fine by adding `os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = HTTPS_PROXY_ADDRESS`

But for Playwright this does not work and it tries to bypass our company proxy and connect directly, which fails because our firewall does not allow this.

BrowserStack has an [example in JS](https://github.com/browserstack/playwright-browserstack/blob/main/google_search_with_proxy.js) that does work so this is not impossible.

But I cannot get this to work in Python. I have tried setting `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `WS_PROXY` and `WSS_PROXY` without success.

Does anyone know how I can force Playwright to use our proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using proxy in playwright and this is how i use it

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


def initiate_browser():
    p = sync_playwright().start()
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page(proxy={"server": "ip_of_your_server"})
    return page
```

Comment: This is how to make the browser started by Playwright use a proxy. But it does not make the initial call out to start the browser use a proxy.

Comment: Are you using firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the below Python equivalent of the sample JS that you shared from the BrowserStack link which you mentioned is working:

```
os.environ['GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://someuser:test123@127.0.0.1:3128'
```

Comment: Adding this setting does not solve the problem.